# How to get iteration count when comparing to arrays in 2 foreach loops using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, comparison

I have 2 arrays that I would like to get a total vote count for. Array one is user proposals and array 2 is user votes on proposals. I am trying to compare the 2 and count the total votes for each proposal.

Here are the 2 arrays -

```
$props = json_decode('[{"proposal":"proposal 1", "owner":"tom", "lock_time":1639440607},{"proposal":"proposal 2", "owner":"bob", "lock_time":1639455554}]', true);

$votes = json_decode('[{"vote":"approve", "owner":"tom", "prop-id":1639440607},{"vote":"reject", "owner":"bob", "prop-id":1639455554},{"vote":"reject", "owner":"tom", "prop-id":1639440607}]', true);
```

The desired output is as follows -

```
Proposal 1 = 1 Approve and 1 Reject
Proposal 2 = 0 Approve and 1 Reject
```

The output im getting is -

```
Proposal 1 = 1 Approve and 1 Reject
Proposal 2 = 1 Approve and 1 Reject
```

Here is my attempt that is not giving the desired output -

```
foreach($props as $props){

    $lock_time = $props['lock_time'];
    $my_proposal = $props['proposal'];

    foreach($votes as $votes){

        $id = $votes['prop-id'];
        $vote = $votes['vote'];

        if($lock_time == $id){
           if($vote == 'approve'){
               $yay++;
           }elseif($vote == 'reject'){
               $nay++;
           }
        }
    }

    echo 'Proposal: '.$my_proposal.'<br>';
    echo 'yay:: '.$yay.'<br>';
    echo 'nay:: '.$nay.'<br>';
    echo '<br><br>';

 }
```

Here is my demo - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/abea2fa828c067ce3efc1440af201fce839645b6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this block
 `if($vote == 'approve'){ $yay++; }elseif($vote == 'reject'){ $nay++;}`

you need to reset the values for each proposal , so the could should like this :

```
foreach($props as $props){

    $lock_time = $props['lock_time'];
    $my_proposal = $props['proposal'];
    $yay=0;
    $nay=0;
    foreach($votes as $vote){

        $id = $vote['prop-id'];
        $theVote = $vote['vote'];

        if($lock_time == $id){
            if($theVote == 'approve'){
                $yay++;
            }elseif($theVote == 'reject'){
                $nay++;
            }

        }
    }
    
    echo 'Proposal: '.$my_proposal.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'yay:: '.$yay.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'nay:: '.$nay.PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Yep that did it thank you so much :-)

Comment: welcome, if its working accept the answer plz

Comment: @RyanD, yeah, I'm surprised the Reject number for Proposal isn't 2 because of this.

Comment: I had to wait a few minutes to accept, its accepted now, thanks again! You are correct there are 2 rejects and one approval, I had it wrong in the expected output.. Nice catch.